# Spacemacs - start popup terminal window in evil-normal-state

Tags: spacemacs, evil, term

I've added these keybinding configuration in my Spacemacs dot file, so that I can toggle the terminal by press the <kbd>\</kbd> key.

```
;; Keybindings
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "\\") 'spacemacs/default-pop-shell)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "\\") 'spacemacs/default-pop-shell)
```

By default, the terminal starts in **evil-insert-state**. However, I have to go to **evil-normal-state** to close the terminal window with  <kbd>\</kbd>, which means, when I open the terminal again, it would be in **evil-normal-state**.

This inconsistence makes me feel bad. How can I make the popup terminal start in evil-normal-state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `(evil-set-initial-state 'term-mode 'normal)` will do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't...

Comment: Does `(evil-set-initial-state 'spacemacs/default-pop-shell 'normal)`?

Comment: No, still not working... However, I found this works: `(evil-set-initial-state 'term-mode 'normal)`. You can edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad that worked out